# Proving the following shrinking lemma for binary covers

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove a topological space is normal if and only if for each pair of open sets $U,V$ such that $U \cup V=X$, there exists open sets $U'$ and $V'$ such that $\overline U' \subset U$ and $\overline V' \subset V$ and $U' \cup V'=X$

Attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Since $U \cup V=X \implies (X-U) \cap (X-V)=\varnothing$. $X-U$ and $X-V$ are disjoint closed sets. Then by normality of $X$, there are disjoint open sets $W,Z$ with $X-U \subset W$ and $X-V \subset Z$, and an equivalent definition of normality states there are open sets $W',Z'$ containing $X-U$ and $X-V$ with $\overline W' \subset W$ and $\overline Z' \subset Z$. Now I am unsure how to show that $W' \cup Z'=X$, which is what I need to show in the problem.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose the second part of the statement holds. Let $A$ be closed in $X$ and $U$ be any open set containing $X$. Then the existence of an open set $U'$ containing $A$ such that $\overline U' \subset U$ implies $X$ is normal.

Comment:I am having difficulty understanding (why/if) $W' \cup Z'=X$ holds in the first direction. Also I am skeptical whether I started the second direction correctly by starting with a closed set, and an arbitrary open set containing this closed set. I also realize it may not be true that $U'$ contains the closed set $A$, which adds to my skepticism. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part of the proof you’re looking at the wrong pair of open sets. What you should do is let $U'=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}W'$ and $V'=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}Z'$. Certainly these are open sets, and

$$\begin{align*}
U'\cup V'&=(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}W')\cup(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}Z')\\
&=X\setminus(\operatorname{cl}W'\cap\operatorname{cl}Z')\\
&=X\,,
\end{align*}$$

since $\operatorname{cl}W'\cap\operatorname{cl}Z'\subseteq W\cap Z=\varnothing$.

In the second part you’ve omitted some crucial steps; in particular, you’ve not explained where $U'$ comes from. You need to let $V=X\setminus A$ and note that $U$ and $V$ are then open sets whose union is $X$; **then** you can apply your hypothesis to get open $U'$ and $V'$ such that $\operatorname{cl}U'\subseteq U$, $\operatorname{cl}V'\subseteq V$, and $U'\cup V'=X$. You need this in order to prove that $A\subseteq U'$.

Specifically, you know that $V'\subseteq V=X\setminus A$, so $V'\cap A=\varnothing$. On the other hand, $A\subseteq X=U'\cup V'$, so it must be the case that $A\subseteq U'$.

Answer (score 0):

I think applying "$X$ normal iff for all closed $A$ and open $O$ with $A \subseteq O$ we have $U$ open with $A \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq O$" is more direct in this case:

Given the cover $\{U,V\}$, consider $V^\complement$, which is closed and a subset of $U$, so there is a $U'$ open such that $$V^\complement \subseteq U' \subseteq \overline{U'} \subseteq U$$ by normality. Then $\{U', V\}$ also covers $X$ (a point not in $V$ is in $U'$) and we do the same again: $U'^\complement$ is closed and a subset of $V$ so we have an open $V'$ such that $$U'^\complement \subseteq V' \subseteq \overline{V'} \subseteq V$$

and then $\{U',V'\}$ is the required cover as is now immediately clear. This procedure easily extends by induction to all finite open covers, of course.

The reverse (that having the refinements implies normality) is quite direct too:
let $A \subseteq O$ where $A$ is closed and $O$ is open, then $\{ A^\complement,O\}$ is an open cover of $X$ so we have refining $\{U',V'\}$ and $U' \subseteq \overline{U'} \subseteq A^\complement$ implies $A \subseteq \overline{U'}^\complement \subseteq U'^\complement$ and the latter closed set is a subset of $V' \subseteq O$ so that, defining $O'= \overline{U'}^\complement$ we have $A \subseteq O' \subseteq \overline{O'} \subseteq O$ showing normality.